# Is there a solution $y(t)$ for $y''+e^ty=0$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} y(t)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a solution $y(t)$ for $y''+e^ty=0$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} y(t)=2021$

If we write the eq as $\dfrac{y''}{e^{-t}}+y=0$ then $y$ cannot be equal to non zero constant because of uniqueness?

How to approach that kind of problem?

Comment: Characteristic equation?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @imranfat That doesn't work because the ODE doesn't have an elemental solution.

Comment: It ıs not constant coefficient eq.

Comment: I didn't catch that e-power. I was thinking in $x$.

Comment: Wondering...is this a book problem?

Comment: exercise problems for upcoming exam week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will prove that $$y''+e^ty = 0 \implies \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t) = 0.$$

Substituting $x=2e^{\frac{t}{2}}$ gives
$$x^2 y'' + xy + x^2y=0$$

The solutions of this equation are known as [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

$$y=c_1 J_0(x) + c_2 Y_0(x).$$

From the link above, we can find that

$$J_0 \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos\left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

$$Y_0 \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

From this, the result above follows easily.